# Template matching for time series using dask

Tags: time-series, dask, template-matching

I would like to use template matching with time-series, and I would like to be able to port this to very large datasets. The objective is to look for many relatively short 1d pattern in a relatively long time-series. Any suggestion on how to do this in Dask? I mean to have something like https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.corr with many `other` and `split_every` equal or lower than length of `other`...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend solving this problem first on pandas dataframes and then using the `map_partitions` method to apply your solution to every pandas dataframe that makes up the dask dataframe.

If your solution requires neighboring rows in order to operate, then I would look at `map_overlap`

- https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions
- https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_overlap

Comment: Thanks a lot it looks quite interesting.